# How to use animation every time image changes with react-spring?

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-hooks, react-spring

I'm trying to use the animation that is used initially when the page loads every time the user clicks next in the image carousel.

I've tried using react-springs similar to this:

```
const springs = useSprings(cards.map(item => ({ opacity: item.opacity }))
```

however I get "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

this is working when using useSpring (non-plural):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useSpring, animated } from "react-spring";
import "./App.css";

const cards = [
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f5/RWS_Tarot_08_Strength.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/53/RWS_Tarot_16_Tower.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/9b/RWS_Tarot_07_Chariot.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/db/RWS_Tarot_06_Lovers.jpg",
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/de/RWS_Tarot_01_Magician.jpg"
];

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const props = useSpring({
    opacity: 1,
    marginTop: 100,
    boxShadow: "0px 100px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)",
    from: { opacity: 0, marginTop: 10 }
  });

  const prevSlide = () => {
    let prevSlide = count - 1 < 0 ? cards.length - 1 : count - 1;
    setCount(prevSlide);
  };

  const nextSlide = () => {
    let nextSlide = count + 1 < cards.length ? count + 1 : 0;
    setCount(nextSlide);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <animated.div style={props}>
          <img src={cards[count]} alt="carousel-img" />
        </animated.div>
      </div>
      <div className="carousel__prev" onClick={prevSlide}>
        ◀︎
      </div>
      <div className="carousel__next" onClick={nextSlide}>
        ▶︎
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How do I get the animation to fade in the image from the top when next is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for the carousel the useTransition function is better than useSprings. You can define the entering and leaving animation with useTransition. When you press the next button the previous and next image have to be overlapped, so I changed the position to absolute. The page layout changed a little this way. You have to fix it.

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const transitions = useTransition([count], item => item, {
    from: { opacity: 0, marginTop: 10, position: 'absolute', boxShadow: "0px 100px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)" },
    enter: { opacity: 1, marginTop: 50},
    leave: {opacity: 0, marginTop: 100}
  });

  const prevSlide = () => {
    let prevSlide = count - 1 < 0 ? cards.length - 1 : count - 1;
    setCount(prevSlide);
  };

  const nextSlide = () => {
    let nextSlide = count + 1 < cards.length ? count + 1 : 0;
    setCount(nextSlide);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        {transitions.map(({item, props, key}) => (
          <animated.div key={key} style={props}>
          {item}
            <img src={cards[item]} alt="carousel-img" />

          </animated.div>
        ))}

      </div>
      <div className="carousel__prev" onClick={prevSlide}>
        ◀︎
      </div>
      <div className="carousel__next" onClick={nextSlide}>
        ▶︎
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is a codeSandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/image-carousel-with-react-spring-usetransition-q1ndd

I the codesandbox example I also introduced a reverse state, because it feels better if I change the animation with the prev button.

Comment: That's funny I was just working on this and started using useTransition instead..it does make more sense here. Also, Is there a way you could credit me partially in the codesandbox or something?  This is a take home quiz for a job I interviewed with and if they find the codesandbox they'll think I just copied/pasted everything!

Comment: I inserted the url of this question.

Comment: @PeterAmbruzs How can I disable animation when the first time render (reload page)?